# Reading comments to deleted questions

Tags: discussion

I logged on and found I had an alert about a comment on [Can I use "Called Shot" with burst fire?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/65924?noredirect=1), which I had put an answer and some comments for. This comment alert was explicitly addressed to me (first word was my username), but upon clicking the comment I find the question has been removed for reasons of moderation.

Now, I don't know if I've done something wrong in my answering or commenting on the question, or whether some other aspect of the question was an issue, but it would help if I could read the comment that had been posted.

Should I even be alerted to a comment I can't actually read due to question removal? If so, shouldn't I be able to read the comment in its entirety, rather than the few words afforded in the recent inbox messages alert?

Comment: first, the specific comment there was: "Ardavion, you've done a fair amount of work on this post. If you want to ask a question to which this post is the answer, you are welcome to do so."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That question was deleted because the querent asked for it. You had put in a large amount of work into your answer, and so I was encouraging you to post a question to which your answer was appropriate.

Unfortunately, your rep isn't high enough to see deleted things which presents something of a quandary. If you have the research elsewhere, everything's golden. If you don't, I'm willing to undelete for 15 minutes for you to rescue your work.

Comment: I'm fine not needing the answer rescuing; I'm quite able to remember the relevant details, and I always have the rulebook if I'm not able :) thanks for the full comment explanation. The thing leading from this, and hence the question, was that I don't understand the need for comment notification on questions that have been deleted/removed, and are thus not able to be seen (at least by people who don't have sufficient reputation). Surely there should be some mechanic for checking alertee reputation and question availability before actually issuing the alert.

Comment: Well, the only people who are able to leave comments on deleted questions are the mods, and in general we're discouraged from doing so. I just left a message because the particular confluence of events I felt was worth an explicit call out to you that your work was valuable.

Comment: Undeletion shouldn't be necessary; any 10k+ rep user can go look at it, view the edit source, and pull the whole answer for resuse, maybe put it in a pastebin or in a chat room here.